# Get type of sibling parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am writing a Graph component, that has a config for `x` and `y` axis.
I want the `GraphProps` to be used like so:

```js
type Stock = {
  timestamp: string;
  value: number;
  company: 'REDHAT' | 'APPLE' | ... ;
}

const props: GraphProps<Stock> = {
  x: {
    dataKey: 'timestamp',
    // type-checks that timestamp is a string
    formatText: timestamp => new Date(timestamp).toDateString()
  },
  y: {
    dataKey: 'company',
    // type-checks that company is 'APPLE' | 'REDHAT' | ...
    formatText: company => company === 'APPLE' ? 'Apple' : company
  }
}
```

I have the following Typescript code:

```js
type AxisType<T> = {
  dataKey: keyof T;
  // i want point to be:
  // T[dataKey]
  // how can I access dataKey from within the formatText
  // type definition?
  formatText: (point: T[keyof T]) => string;
}

type GraphProps<T> = {
  x: AxisType<T>;
  y: AxisType<T>;
}
```

however with the current definition the `formatText` type is `Stock[keyof Stock]` which equals `Stock['timestamp' | 'value' | 'company']`, when what I want is, if the provided `dataKey` is `company`, i would like for the `formatText` type to be `Stock['company']`.

I thought of extending the `GraphProps` generic type with 2 more type parameters(`GraphProps<T, XDataKey, YDataKey>`), however I might add more than two axes and/or dynamically many more axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `AxisType<T>` and `GraphProps<T>` like this:

```
type AxisType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    dataKey: K;
    formatText: (point: T[K]) => string;
  };
}[keyof T];

type GraphProps<T> = {
  [axis: string]: AxisType<T>;
};
```

Comment: i'm just having a problem with the compiler automatically inferring `T` now, i.e. without passing the `Stock` in `Graph<Stock>`, if you have any idea that can help the compiler.

Comment: @Henke unless you have a value of type `Stock` or a value of a type that's a container of `Stock` at the time you initialize `props`, there's no way to get `GraphProps` to infer `T`.

Comment: I think I've misformulated my question, what I mean, can I do that without *explicitly* passing the type parameter. I have a `const stocks: Stock[]`, and suppose that the `GraphProps` has an additional property `data: T[]`, and I initialize my Graph component like: `<Graph data={stocks} x={...} y={...}/>`, so that the compiler infers `T` from the `data` property.

However now I have to write: `<Graph<Stock> data={stocks} x={...} y={...}/>`, which is not bad by all means! but if there was a way for it to automatically infer it would be better. Right now the inferred type is `never` :P

Comment: @Henke does `type GraphProps<T> = {
      data: T[];
      x: AxisType<T>;
      y: AxisType<T>;
    };` not work the way you want?

Comment: it does work the way I want, it's just the Typescript compiler that's not correctly inferring the `T` parameter, when I update the `AxisType` definition and use yours. I do not why, it's not inferring correctly, and requires me to pass the type parameter.